# Can not Upgrade AKS worker nodes to protect against CVE-2021-25741

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade, azure-aks

I was trying to upgrade my Azure AKS to protect against CVE-2021-25741.

I had seen that the following versions are affected:

[image: Affected Versions]

I cannot upgrade my cluster to any of the versions above.

When I run the following command

`az aks get-versions --location westeurope --output table`

I get this:

[image: Azure Versions]

So the question is how can I upgrade to a non-affected version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to wait until the AKS Team is releasing a Kubernetes Version were this is fixed.

Until then, you can leverage Azure Policy & Gatekeeper to mitigate the attack scenario: https://sysdig.com/blog/cve-2021-25741-kubelet-falco/

Comment: the Version 1.19.15 is released at (released: 2021-09-15)
https://kubernetes.io/releases/
but the question is why i cant update to this release

Comment: bcs AKS has a different Version release cycle than upstream Kubernetes. It takes some time for the developers from Azure. Thats why you need to wait a little and implement the Gatekeeper fix until then.